# Window Sum based on condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to use the window function to create a column that sums the revenue in a particular year. For example, I need a column to be the revenue by user in 2020.

```
╔══════╦════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ year ║ userid ║ orderid ║ revenue ║
╠══════╬════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 2019 ║      1 ║ a1      ║      50 ║
║ 2020 ║      1 ║ a2      ║     100 ║
║ 2020 ║      1 ║ a3      ║      50 ║
║ 2019 ║      2 ║ b1      ║     100 ║
║ 2020 ║      2 ║ b2      ║     100 ║
╚══════╩════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

I can use a sub query to achieve the same, but I am wondering if I can use the window function to do this?

```
 select *, sum(revenue) over (partition by year, userid) as 2020_user_revenue
 from table
```

Currently have:

```
╔══════╦════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ year ║ userid ║ orderid ║ revenue ║ 2020_user_revenue ║
╠══════╬════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 2019 ║      1 ║ a1      ║      50 ║                50 ║
║ 2020 ║      1 ║ a2      ║     100 ║               150 ║
║ 2020 ║      1 ║ a3      ║      50 ║               150 ║
║ 2019 ║      2 ║ b1      ║     100 ║               100 ║
║ 2020 ║      2 ║ b2      ║     100 ║               100 ║
╚══════╩════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Expected:

```
╔══════╦════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ year ║ userid ║ orderid ║ revenue ║ 2020_user_revenue ║
╠══════╬════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 2019 ║      1 ║ a1      ║      50 ║               150 ║
║ 2020 ║      1 ║ a2      ║     100 ║               150 ║
║ 2020 ║      1 ║ a3      ║      50 ║               150 ║
║ 2019 ║      2 ║ b1      ║     100 ║               100 ║
║ 2020 ║      2 ║ b2      ║     100 ║               100 ║
╚══════╩════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Not sure you're going to achieve much using a window function here. Your attempt is simply adding up all orders for that userid over all years not just 2020. Since the window function OVER clause is designed to select data relative to the current row I'm not sure this would be very easy. In addition your expected output is also grouped by orderid and your attempt includes a * and no group by clause so you're bound to get something with orderid in it.

Comment: Thank you Simon, you are right. I have edited my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this below script-

```
SELECT *,
sum(CASE WHEN year =2020 then rev else 0 end) over (partition by userid) as 2020_user_revenue 
FROM
(
    select Year,userid, SUM(revenue) Rev
    from your_table
    GROUP BY Year,userid
)A
ORDER BY userid
```

Output is-

```
Year    userid  Rev     2020_user_revenue
2019    1       50      150
2020    1       150     150
2019    2       100     100
2020    2       100     100
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! with your query, the last column will not have value if the year is not 2020. I would need the 2020 revenue being populated for each row.

Comment: Sum of 2020 is populated for each row for a specific userid. You can check the output I have added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a conditional window function:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when year = 2020 then revenue else 0
           end) over (partition by userid) as revenue_2020
from t;
```